# PHP not working correctly in WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have made a plain PHP widget to be displayed on a WordPress sidebar. I have successfully made the widget post the data I am hoping to have filled in on the consecutive page. However where it is supposed to be will not fill in, instead it fills in with `"<?php echo $_GET["` then after the text box `" />"`. I am hoping that the email first submitted will fill in on the form on the next page. The code that I have for the registration form is part of a greater widget and looks like the following:

```
<p class="form-email'.$errorVar.'">
      <label for="email">'. __('E-mail', 'profilebuilder') .$errorMark.'</label>
      <input class="text-input" name="email" type="text" id="email" value="<?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?>" /> 
</p><!-- .form-email -->';
```

Here is a link to the page: http://universityoutfitters.com/testphp/ — the widget is on the bottom left hand side panel.

Additional information:
The code for the widget is as follows:

```
<form action="http://universityoutfitters.com/sign-up/" method="post">
    Please submit your email address
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: You can't mix PHP and HTML like that, wrap all your PHP code in `<?php ?>`.

Comment: You mean the get variable doesn't work for you?

Comment: value="<?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?>"       Is it not wrapped?

Comment: @AlexanderCharles - @bfavaretto  is referring to your `<label>` tag.

Comment: You're stepping into PHP without a declaration here:
`"email">'. __('E-mail'`

Answer (score 1):

This line should be:

```
<label for="email"><?php echo __('E-mail', 'profilebuilder') $errorMark ;?></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comments told above, you have to wrap it correctly with PHP tags

```
<?php
echo '<p class="form-email'.$errorVar.'">
      <label for="email">'. __('E-mail', 'profilebuilder') .$errorMark.'</label>
      <input class="text-input" name="email" type="text" id="email" value="'.$_GET["email"].'" /> 
</p><!-- .form-email -->';
?>
```

Comment: This creates a larger error and does not allow the site to load.